# Three wordpress sites to share same data

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have multiple domains like:
www.site1.com, www.site2.com, www.site3.com

I want them all to share same DB tables except WP_OPTIONS table. This is because each site will act as "separate" entity but will still have same pages, posts, products etc...

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get why do you need this kind of feature, the SEO of this will be baaaad :)

However several plugins let you spread posts into a Wordpress network installation.

[DiamondMultisite](http://wordpress.org/plugins/diamond-multisite-widgets/) allows you to publish posts in all the blogs in a wordpress multisite install, i guess it works with pages

There is also [ThreeWP Broadcast](http://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) which support more content and also seems to be more active.

Comment: Thanks for reply and suggestions, but I really need solution to share DB for several other reasons... so I just can't use plugins.

Comment: I hope your reasons are good enough :) If you can't use plugins, then go for the @Gerald solution ...

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the used DB table names in each installation: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/share-certain-parts-of-a-wp-database-over-2-domains

Quote from the linked site:

```
Edit the wp-db.php file in the wp-includes directory.
In the function set_prefix($prefix) section

After :

foreach ( $this->tables as $table )
$this->$table = $this->prefix . $table;

Added :
$this->options = 'wp_' . 'options';
```

more tables:

```
$this->posts = 'wp_' . 'posts';
$this->categories = 'wp_' . 'categories';
$this->options = 'wp2_' . 'options';
$this->links = 'wp2_' . 'links';
$this->postmeta = 'wp_' . 'postmeta';
$this->terms = 'wp_' . 'terms';
$this->term_taxonomy = 'wp_' . 'term_taxonomy';
$this->term_relationships = 'wp_' . 'term_relationships';
```

Drawback: This file is prone to be overwritten during a WordPress update.

Additional note: I agree with x4vier that the SEO results will be bad. I wouldn't recommend the whole concept.

Comment: In WP 3.5.1 there is no such line

Comment: It's a little different, but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.